# AS3 URLRequest XSS?

Tags: actionscript-3, xss, cross-domain, urlrequest

Im basically working on an image analyser that downloads images from another server. I have no control over the server but I only want to scan images not html pages.

would something like this work?

```
new URLRequest('http://otherserver.com/someimage.jpg');
```

Or would I have to use a PHP script to act as a proxy for my script and have the swf look up that php script with parameters instead?

```
new URLRequest('http://myserver.com/proxy.php?image=someimage.jpg');
```

I only ask because I remembered AJAX requests wont work cross domain so I wondered if the same thing affects AS3 aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cross-domain-policy:

http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html